# Reference Books on Electrolysis and Chemical Titration process

Tags: experimental-chemistry, ph, titration, electrolysis

I'm in a General Chemistry course in college. We have laboratory, and then we are supposed to make a report on what we did, etc.

I'm not entirely sure what the last laboratory was about, but it was called **Salt and Water Electrolysis**

To sum up the procedures -two general procedures-, here's what we did:

1st Procedure:

- We prepared 50 mL of a $\ce{NaCl(aq)}$ solution at 0.1 M (molarity) in a 100 mL beaker
- We made a DC (direct current) circuit at 5V and 700 mA, with graphite electrodes
- We turned the circuit on for roughly 20 minutes
- We employed a magnetic stirrer to stir the solution
- We added 3 drops of Phenolphthalein in the solution, and took notes of the phenomena. (I guess it kinda turned pink)

And that was that for the 1st procedure.

2nd procedure:

- We measured the solution's pH with a pH meter
- We measured roughly 15 mL of $\ce{HCl}$ (Hydrochloric Acid) at 0.5 M with a test tube
- We poured the solution of $\ce{HCl}$ in a 25 mL burette.
- We prepared the titration equipment
- We were supposed to add the $\ce{HCl}$ (drop by drop) to the $\ce{NaCl}$ solution and at the same time be measuring the pH until it got to 7

And that was that for the second procedure.

Of course we kind of messed up, as we overshot the end point. The excess $\ce{HCl}$ brought it's pH to 3 point something.

The $\ce{NaCl}$ solution lost its pink color, and then turned yellowish.

So.. I guess I am asking for references to the equipment involved -I kind of have references for the pH and the properties involved, still, if you know of some references, let me know!-, I've looked for electrolysis processes in books but don't find any. Or they're too technical. Also, haven't found titration procedures in books.

Can you help me out, just so I can finish my report?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! I wish to politely draw your attention to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233) post. Please make a note of it while creating future posts!

Comment: It is always good to read about the experiment before going to the lab. As a result, then you don't need to use expletives. There are very good Youtube videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nAe_T5mO2o

Comment: No expletive needed alright. My apologies. And thank you :D

Comment: I just want to add: the reports require bibliographical links, and I don't think they'll allow youtube videos as a reference..

Comment: I mean, I do kind of know what happens. The types of reaction taking place, but I have to back it up with bibliographical references.

Comment: You're much better served by asking your TA, professor, lab instructor, etc. for details regarding what the references should entail than ask a bunch of strangers about something that doesn't necessarily have any analogy to the standards of professional publications.

Comment: I guess you're right bro..

Answer (score 1):

Any good general chemistry textbook has a chapter on electrolysis. If you wish to add more scholarly work check the Journal of Chemical Education. https://pubs.acs.org/action/doSearch?text1=Electrolysis&quickLinkYear=&quickLinkVolume=&field1=Title&type=within&publication=346464552

In the first part you electrolyze a solution of salt. Check the half cell reactions from the text: What happens at the cathode and what happens at the anode?

Water is reduced at the cathode and -OH ions are produced. This makes your salt solution basic. In the second part, your lab requires you to estimate how much base was produced.*

Essentially you do a titration of NaOH with standardized HCl. The end point is estimated by a pH meter. Look up any general chemistry textbook again for titration of a base with HCl using a pH meter. The technique is called pH titration. You did a very rough version of a pH titration.

---

- Depending on the conc. of NaCl, either chlorine or oxygen is produced at the anode.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
Just 20 minutes ago, I found a nice resource.
"Chemistry - The Central Science" 14th edition in SI units by Brown had all I needed, I think.
There's almost all of what I needed on pH and acid-base stuff on chapter 16.
Now, on electrolysis, I guess that's a little more advanced so it's until chapter 20, section 9 (20.9) that there's a whole section on electrolysis.
And yes!, now I know I titrated the solution with the Phenolph, pretty cool..